# Different browsers, PCs continue to load cached script even after clearing cache

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I made an update to a JS file and uploaded via FTP. But when I refresh the page, the old version of the script still seems to be loading.

I know the initial first steps, so I've done this already:

- Cleared cache and history from browsers
- Tried 3 browsers (safari, chrome, firefox) all after clearing cache
- Tried 2 different PCs, an iphone and an ipad
- Tried force refresh on all PCs/browsers
- Tried using safari and chrome developer tools to disable cache
- Added tags to header to not cache this page (I'm not sure if that would work retroactively or just prevent the problem in the future)
- Tried from two different networks which I think have different ISPs

Here's the real kicker: when I view source, in all of these case above, I'm seeing the updated file. It's driving me crazy. What else can I try? What is going on here.

I'm new here and not used to using this, but here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L14s0c80/1/)

Here's the code that's been changed:

```
document.getElementById("dataPopup").innerHTML = "<p>The Overall   Neighborhood Score gives equal weight to the Social Disadvantage, Prestige, Business and Employment, Housing Type and Tenure, and Crime Indexes. A neighborhood score of zero is average for Detroit. A positive score indicates above average economic strength and a negative score conveys below average economic strength.</p><a href='#' onClick='hideDataPopup()'>Close</a>"
```

If it helps, here's the site: [Detroit Community Metrics](http://matthewiannowlin.com/planning/detroit/) After loading, click "More info..." and it should read "A neighborhood score of zero is average for Detroit." instead of "A neighborhood score of zero is average for the Detroit."

Comment: 1. where is the jsfiddle. 2. have you added cachebusters? (?r=2), 3, no cache headers don't work retroactively, 4 network doesn't matter if you are in the same browser

Comment: What's happening with the old script and what should be happening with the new one? (If you do provide a jsFiddle, don't forget that the code must also be added to the question itself.)

Comment: Cachebusters being when you add some nonsense argument to the URL that calls the script? Like this: <script src="js/main.js?something=1234"></script>

Comment: All I changed was some simple text. The text in a particular popup box is not showing my updates. Just changed a couple words.

Comment: I would say there is a very good chance you are not changing the right text

Comment: So as a test for that I searched the updated JS file for a word that was only in the previous text (the word healthy). It was not found in the updated document. So the browser is definitely not getting the script content from the newest version

Comment: i've even tried saving the script with a new name and linking to that script instead. The html is not cached, the browser links to the right script (the renamed script) and still the old script is running.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* See the [help] for more info on asking and [edit] your question to include the smallest amount of code to duplicate the problem.

Comment: I downloaded your site and found a scripting issue which I think probably accounts for the problem: the 'overall' case on line 2329 of main.js is not executed on initial page load, so the text in your update isn't changed. It is executed if you select another option from the dropdown, select 'Overall Neighborhood Score' again, and then click 'More info...', at which point the popup text is altered.

Comment: This turned out to be a silly question. The comment above is correct. On initial page load, the text is drawn from the HTML file, not the script. So obviously changing the script didn't change the text. Should I just delete the question?

Comment: I think it's fine to delete it if you wish, I could post my comment as an answer (which is really what I should've done in the first place), but I'm not sure there's much point. I don't think it was a silly question as such by the way, I'm sure we've all had situations like this where it's difficult to establish exactly what's going on.